# .bat file renaming folders, changing first letter of every word to uppercase

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, rename

From `C:\x\adrenaline_-_shut_the_fug_up_and_dance-2000`

to `C:\x\Adrenaline_-_Shut_The_Fug_Up_And_Dance-2000`

I had this code but it capitalize every single letter instead

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
echo Renaming folders
for /d %%F in (C:\x\*) do (
  for /f "eol= " %%A in ("%%~nxF") do (
    set "name=%%F"
    set "newName=%%A"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    for %%C in (
        A B C D E F G H I J K L M
        N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
    ) do set "newName=!newName:%%C=%%C!"
    ren "!name!" "!newName!"
    endlocal
  )
)
```

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this modification? I think that this might be able to write more simpler. So please think of this as one of several answers.

#### Modification points :

- Retrieve the initial letter from filename, and convert it to uppercase.
- For each initial letter in the filename, retrieve the letter using `_`. And the letter of behind `_` is converted to uppercase.
- Add the converted letter to the filename which was removed the initial letter.
- If there is the same filename, it is not renamed.

The modified script which reflected above points is as follows.

#### Modified script :

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
ECHO Renaming folders

SET "DIR=C:\x\"

FOR /D %%F IN (%DIR%*) DO (
  SET "BASENAME=%%~NXF"
  SET "NAME=%%~NXF"
  SET "F=TRUE"
  SET "NEWNAME="
  CALL :CONVERT
)
EXIT /B

:CONVERT
SET "L=!NAME:~0,1!"
IF %F% == TRUE (
  SET "INITIAL=!L!"
  FOR %%I IN (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) DO SET INITIAL=!INITIAL:%%I=%%I!
  SET NEWNAME=!NEWNAME!!INITIAL!
) ELSE (
  SET NEWNAME=!NEWNAME!!L!
)
IF !L! == _ (
  SET "F=TRUE"
) ELSE (
  SET "F=FALSE"
)
SET "NAME=!NAME:~1!"
IF DEFINED NAME GOTO CONVERT
IF NOT %DIR%!BASENAME! == %DIR%!NEWNAME! REN "%DIR%!BASENAME!" "!NEWNAME!"
EXIT /B
```

#### Note :

- When you use this, please modify `SET "DIR=C:\x\"` for your environment.
- Please be careful `_` of the filename, because the letters for converting to the uppercase are retrieved using `_`.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.